# Unable to read file

Tags: python, python-2.6

Why can I not read what I have just written to the text file. The code does not show any errors but I am not able to read what I just wrote to the document. If someone could help me figure this out that would be great. I am new to programming by the way so forgive me if this is a simple problem.I am using Python version 2.6.1

```
from sys import argv

script,file_name = argv
prompt = "> "

target = open(file_name, 'w+b')

print "press CRTL-C enter to escape this"
print "or press RETURN to continue"

raw_input(prompt)

print "Begin erasing stuff Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "we are going to start writing to file"

write_1 = raw_input(prompt)
write_2 = raw_input(prompt)
write_3 = raw_input(prompt)

target.write(write_1)
target.write(write_2)
target.write(write_3)

print target.read()


print "closing now!"
target.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `target.seek(0)` to reset the file pointer to the start of of the file before doing `target.read()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that opening in `"w"` mode truncates the file automatically, so it might be easier to open in that mode, write to the file, then open in `"r"` mode. That was you avoid having to truncate manually and seek back:

```
from sys import argv

script, file_name = argv
prompt = "> "

print("Press CTRL+C to exit,")
print("or press RETURN to continue.")

raw_input(prompt)

print("Begin erasing.")
with open(file_name, 'wb') as target:
    print("Begin writing to file.")
    write_1 = raw_input(prompt)
    write_2 = raw_input(prompt)
    write_3 = raw_input(prompt)
    target.write(write_1)
    target.write(write_2)
    target.write(write_3)

with open(file_name, "rb") as target:
    print(target.read())
```

I'm also using [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for [opening files](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement). It's not only more pythonic and readable but handles closing for you, even when exceptions occur.

It's worth noting that at the moment, this gives you output that is all on one line, as the writes do not add a newline, and `raw_input()` does not give you the newline that caused it to continue. As such, you probably want to add them in. We can also just use a single `write()` commands with a single string concatenated from all of our input:

```
print("we are going to start writing to file")
data = [raw_input(prompt) for _ in range(3)]
target.write("\n".join(data))
```

Here I use [a list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) to build up a list of the input lines. This means we don't have to write out `line_x = raw_input(prompt)` a load of times, and we can easily change the number of lines we want to use. It also means we can easily use `str.join()` to add in the newlines we wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out explanation.I am barely learning python and you explaining it like you did really helped.